# What would kill you first if you fell into a sarlacc's mouth?

Tags: star-wars, sarlacc

Would you suffocate, drown, starve, or die from lack of water first in a sarlacc, if you made it past the mouth alive?

Comment: Since 3CPO advertises that Han Solo will "will find a new definition of pain and suffering" as he is "slowly digested over a thousand years" I assume digestion will kill you first (but only after a thousand years).

Comment: Some of the [Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sarlacc/Legends) works indeed suggest that the Sarlacc puts you in a state of some sort of stasis as it slowly digests you, but I don't believe the Disney canon has backed that up.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots my comment/quote was a lame attempt at humor (which on second thought might be not quite appropriate on a question of a new user).

Comment: Ones might die of embarrassment…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sarlacc):

> .... Victims of the sarlacc would be overcome with toxic fumes and would either die from suffocation, the acid or both. According to Jabba the Hutt, prey were allegedly digested for millennia due to the creature's weak stomach acid. However, it is unknown if this was a fabrication by Jabba to intimidate those who were to be executed, as it would seem that the creature did have a slow digestive system. During Boba Fett's escape, he spotted the body of a stormtrooper that was likely part of a search party years before. Despite this, the stomach acid of the sarlacc was still potent enough to have dissolved holes in the stormtrooper's armor and scar Boba Fett after only hours of exposure. Likewise, the stormtrooper was seemingly dead by the time Fett found their body, meaning regardless of how slow the digestion is, prey would likely not survive long before either suffocating or being dissolved.